# Ionic Vue Exoplayer

Tags: vue.js, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, exoplayer

How can I use Android Exoplayer on Ionic? I am using Ionic + Vue

`import { AndroidExoPlayer }  from '@ionic-native/android-exoplayer'`

`created () { console.log(AndroidExoPlayer) }`

I tried this but logging me with. `undefined`

How will I set it correctly in vue? Am I missing something?

`"@ionic-native/android-exoplayer": "^5.34.0",` --- version of ionic android exoplayer.

Comment: Hi Peter Parker, 
Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Got any updates?